# Click event not firing on MenuItem with submenu

Tags: node-webkit, nw.js

In my nw.js app I have a menubar with a 'Parent' menuitem.  'Parent' has both a click event and a submenu.  I noticed the click event on parent does not trigger when there is a submenu.  Is there any way to capture the click event on the parent menuitem of the submenu? Or is this simply expected behavior?

```
    var menubar = new window.gui.Menu({ type: 'menubar' });
    var fileMenu = new window.gui.Menu();
    fileMenu.append(new window.gui.MenuItem({
        label: 'New',
        click: function() {
            window.alert("New");
        }
    }));
    fileMenu.append(new window.gui.MenuItem({
        label: 'Open',
        click: function() {
            window.alert("Open");
        }
    }));
    menubar.append(new window.gui.MenuItem({
        label: 'Parent',
        submenu: fileMenu,
        click: function() {
            window.alert("Does not fire when submenu set");
        }
    }));
    window.win.menu = menubar;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. In other desktop applications, you also don't see a menu item without a submenu attached to it...